# Having trouble with RBT tree and using methods on Node class

Tags: java, binary-tree, red-black-tree

So for class, I was given and RBT class that has a node class within in it. This node class was originally made generic, but I made it so it took the type StudentData. This StudentData class has getter and setter methods, along with a constructor for two fields: a string "name" and a double "grade." (`StudentData (double grade, String name) { this.grade = grade; this.name = name; }`)

In my RBT class, we have a constructor in the node class that initializes a field of StudentData data to equal the parameter passed through which is StudentData data. (`public Node(StudentData data) { this.data =  data; this.isBlack = false;}`)

The problem I am running into is that I want the tree to insert based on the grade, not the overall object. So I tried using node.data.getGrade() and node.getGrade(), but it continues saying "the method getName() is undefined for the type StudentData" and has a quickfix of "add cast to node.data"

What exactly is the issue here? My student class DOES have the method .getGrade().

Comment: can you post all the code?

Comment: I can post small parts but not the whole thing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without a minimal working example. I'm going to give it a shot. Based on what you wrote the inference is you have the following. Forget for a moment that it's red-black, that detail doesn't really matter for this problem. With just a regular BST you have:

```
class Test<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    class Node<T> {
        T data;
        Node<T> left;
        Node<T> right;
        Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    Node<T> search(Node<T> root, T data) {
        if (root == null || root.data == data || root.data.equals(data)) {
            return root;
        }
        if (root.data.compareTo(data) < 0) {
            return search(root.right, data);
        }
        return search(root.left, data);
    }
    // etc ...
}
```

Looking at just the search method, you need to compare the whole data object.

Now throw a StudentData class into the mix. It **has to implement Comparable** otherwise you have no way of comparing it to another StudentData with a generic as just defined.

```
class StudentData implements Comparable<StudentData> {
    final String name;
    final double grade;
    StudentData(String name, double grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StudentData o) {
        return Double.compare(this.grade, o.grade);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        StudentData that = (StudentData) o;
        return Double.compare(that.grade, grade) == 0 && Objects.equals(name, that.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, grade);
    }
}
```

Note that here we can compare based on the grade because it's defined right within the student data class.

Comment: Thanks! So there is no way to compared based on the grade?

Comment: You can compare based on the grade the way I wrote it, look at the `StudentData` class and what the `compareTo` method does